# Flutter update ui when fetching from API

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I'm using `FutureBuilder` for fetching API request. but it only builds once and it doesn't update ui unless hot reloded. i aslo tried `StreamBuilder` and convert the `future` method to `stream`. so how can i update my ui.

model

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<User> usersFromJson(String str) =>
    List<User>.from(json.decode(str).map((json) => User.fromJson(json)));
String usersToJson(List<User> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((e) => e.toJson())));

class User {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  String? username;
  String? email;
  String? role;

  User({this.id, this.name, this.username, this.email, this.role});

  @override
  toString() => 'User: $name';

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
      email: json['email'],
      name: json['name'],
      id: json['id'],
      username: json['username'],
      role: json['role']);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {"name": name, "username": username, "email": email, "role": role};
}
```

api call

```
Future fetchUsers() async {
  Uri url = Uri.parse("${BASE_URL}user");
  final response = await http.get(url, headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $TOKEN',
  });

  var userview = <User>[];

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonres = json.decode(response.body);
    for (var res in jsonres) {
      userview.add(User.fromJson(res));
    }
  }
  return userview;
}

Future createUser(String name, String username, String email, String password,
    String roles) async {
  Uri url = Uri.parse("${BASE_URL}user");
  final response = await http
      .post(url,
          headers: <String, String>{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer $TOKEN',
          },
          body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
            'name': name,
            'email': email,
            'username': username,
            'password': password,
            'roles': roles
          }))
      .then((value) => fetchUsers());
}
```

and my page

```
StreamBuilder(
                        stream: fetchUsers().asStream(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return Column(
                              children: [
                                PaginatedDataTable(
                                    sortColumnIndex: sortColumnIndex,
                                    sortAscending: isAscending,
                                    columns: [
                                      DataColumn(
                                          label: const Text("Id"),
                                          onSort: onSort),
                                      DataColumn(
                                          label: const Text("Name"),
                                          onSort: onSort),
                                      DataColumn(
                                          label: const Text("Username"),
                                          onSort: onSort),
                                      DataColumn(
                                          label: const Text("Email"),
                                          onSort: onSort),
                                      DataColumn(
                                          label: const Text("Roles"),
                                          onSort: onSort),
                                      DataColumn(
                                          label: const Text("Actions"),
                                          onSort: onSort),
                                    ],
                                    header: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          "Manage Users",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: width * 0.04,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                                        ),
                                        MaterialButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
                                                context: context,
                                                builder: (context) => SizedBox(
                                                      height: height * 0.9,
                                                      child:
                                                          BottomSheetWidget(),
                                                    ),
                                                shape:
                                                    const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                        borderRadius:
                                                            BorderRadius.only(
                                                                topLeft: Radius
                                                                    .circular(
                                                                        15),
                                                                topRight: Radius
                                                                    .circular(
                                                                        15))));
                                          },
                                          color: const Color.fromRGBO(
                                              30, 119, 66, 1),
                                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Add User",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontSize: width * 0.03),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    source: dataSource(
                                        snapshot.data! as List<User>))
                              ],
                            );
                          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                          }
                          return const Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                        })
```

additionally i'm using paginated datatable and this is the code for that.(it's related)

in the page

```
DataTableSource dataSource(List<User> userList) =>
      MyTable(datasList: userList, context: context);
```

and the datasource page i'm calling the `createUser` here.

```
class MyTable extends DataTableSource {
  MyTable({required this.datasList, required this.context});
  final List<User> datasList;
  BuildContext context;

  Widget Button(String title, Color color, String id) {
    return MaterialButton(
      onPressed: () {
        //deleteUser(id);
        //updateUser(id, title);
        createUser("name2", "user2", "email2@email.com", "password", "Admin");
      },
      child: Text(
        title,
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      color: color,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
    );
  }

  @override
  DataRow? getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow.byIndex(index: index, cells: [
      DataCell(Text(datasList[index].id.toString())),
      DataCell(ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 100),
        child: Text(
          datasList[index].name.toString(),
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
      )),
      DataCell(ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 100),
          child: Text(
            datasList[index].username.toString(),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ))),
      DataCell(ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 100),
          child: Text(
            datasList[index].email.toString(),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ))),
      DataCell(ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 100),
          child: Text(
            datasList[index].role.toString(),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ))),
      DataCell(Row(
        children: [
          Button("Edit", Colors.lightBlue, datasList[index].id.toString()),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Button("Delete", Colors.red, datasList[index].id.toString()),
        ],
      )),
    ]);
  }

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get rowCount => datasList.length;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it showing any error in console?

Comment: @PratulPant no error. it works fine. but it doesn't update ui unless hot reload

Answer (score 0):

In your `StreamBuilder` you call `fetchUsers()` but you only call it once. The fact that the `createUsers` function also calls it doesn't affect the `Streambuilder` and therefore it doesn't update.  You need to create a property field that is a Future of the type that `fetchUsers()` returns, and have a `FutureBuilder` listen to that property field. Whenever the `createUser` method changes anything it should complete that property field, and because the `FutureBuilder` is listening to that same future, it will rebuild.

I'd also suggest picking the appropriate strategy: if this is a stream of changes, use a property field that is a Stream, feed it with new data and listen to it with a `StreamBuilder`. Alternatively, if it is a value that changes frequently, use a `ValueListenable` and a `ValueListenableBuilder`, and if it is a value that only changes once (e.g. wait for one API call to complete before showing anything) then use a `Future` and a `FutureBuilder` - but don't mix them up.

Comment: can you give me an example or an article to read on this? i'm confused on how to make it right

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html